# subversion on apache - checkout failed: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, httpd, webdav

I try to setup subversion on an apache server. I followed this guide:
[http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion][1]

If I try to checkout afterwards with Tortoise SVN a project I get the following Error:

```
Unexpected HTTP status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/repos
```

If I try to use the svn client on the linux server itself I get the follwing error:

```
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://server.ch/repos'
```

My current configuration on the apache server look like this:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<VirtualHost *:443>
...
  <Directory "/var/www/svn/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorization Realm"
    AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/svn-auth-conf
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>
  <Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/repos
    SVNListParentPath on
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorization Realm"
    AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/svn-auth-conf
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you for any suggestion or help in advance

regards
Mark

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue, the Location and SVNParentPath has been wrongly set. I followed the solution here [http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/35525-Stuck-with-error-%E2%80%9C405-Method-Not-Allowed%E2%80%9D][1]

the correct config on apache looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ...
  <Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorization Realm"
    AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/svn-auth-conf
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your Apache config disable this `OPTIONS` method used by SVN. You may enable this method inside `<Directory "/var/www/svn/">`

```
<Directory "/var/www/svn/">
   ...other config here
   <Limit OPTIONS>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
    </Limit>
   ...other config here
 </Directory>
```

You must know what security implication to enable this METHOD. For all HTTP methods used by SVN, please refer to [official documentation](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-methods).